# Webcams that work in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, webcam

My Logitech Quickcam has no drivers for Windows 7 or Vista for that matter.

Does anyone know of a webcam, with built in mic, not made by Logitech that will work with Windows 7?

Comment: Gosh I have a legacy webcam that works without a problem, so I don't expect any problems getting it too work. Does your Quickcam work on Windows XP?

Comment: My Logitech Quickcam Fusion works great with Windows 7. Which model do you have?

Comment: It's this one http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/480/3378&hub=1&cl=gb,en?osid=13 definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft LifeCam VX-3000](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826105059) works with Windows 7 as confirmed in the comments and on multiple sites, even though it's only marked as XP SP2 and Vista compatible. It comes with a built in Microphone and for $26.99 and free shipping it's a bargain and a half.

Comment: I'm quite liking the look of this one.  I've seen a few people moaning about the sound quality though.

Comment: They have a few other models on newegg that are a bit more expensive if you wanna take a peak. This one's also very cheap so you could disable the microphone and buy a separate one if that's a possibility for you.